# How to deduce template argument from a function type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, function-templates, class-template

I have a class template which has two parameters.

```
template <typename Func, typename T>
struct action_ final : public parser_base<action_<Func, T>, T>
```

The first one is a function type, and the second one is a char like type such as `char`.

I have this code which builds **OK**

```
auto p1 = action_<myTestAction*, char>(testAction);
```

Here, I have to specify the two template arguments, while if I wrote below:

```
auto p2 = action_(testAction);
```

I get a build error that the class template argument deduction failed.

---

Here is the full test code below which need C++20, where the `testAction` is a function.

```
#include <span>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct Token {};
template <typename T>  struct Viewer;

// explicit specialization for T = Token
template <>  struct Viewer<Token> {
    using type = std::span<Token>; // std::span or derived class
};
// explicit specialization for T = char
template <> struct Viewer<char> {
    using type = std::string_view;
};

// alias template
template <typename T> using ViewerT = typename Viewer<T>::type;

template <typename Base, typename T> struct parser_base {
    using v = ViewerT<T>;
    using charType = T;
};

template <typename Func, typename T>
struct action_ final : public parser_base<action_<Func, T>, T> 
{
    constexpr explicit action_(Func&& func) noexcept
        : func(std::forward<Func>(func))
    {}

    template<typename V, typename Skipper>
    constexpr inline bool visit(V& sv, Skipper& skipper) const& noexcept {
        return func(sv); // func returns false to fail the parse
    }

private:
    Func func;
};

using myTestAction = bool(std::string_view& sv);
constexpr bool testAction(std::string_view& sv) {  return true;  }

int main()
{
    auto p1 = action_<myTestAction*, char>(testAction);

    // build error: class template argument deduction failed
    // auto p2 = action_(testAction); 
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT1:**

JeJo's answer suggest that I need to use the deduction guide, but I'm still not sure whether the deduction guide can support several function types.

I mean in my test code, the function type is `bool(std::string_view& sv)`, in this case, the `T` is actually `char`, but in other cases, the function type could be `bool(std::span<Token>)`, where the `T` is actually `Token` type.

My initial guess is that the second template argument `T` is depend on the first template argument function type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to deduce a template argument from a function type?

You can always provide a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Deduction_for_class_templates) for your class template

```
template <typename Func, typename T = char>
action_(Func) ->action_<Func, T>;
```

That been said, you can generalize the deduction guide for any function pointer type, where the argument type of it can be extracted by a type trait, and we make it as default template argument for the deduction guide.

```
// traits for finding the arg type!
template <typename T> struct function;
template <typename ReType, typename Arg> struct function<ReType(*)(Arg)> {
    using arg_type = Arg;
};

// type alias for convenience.
template <typename FunctionPtr> 
using function_arg_t = typename function<FunctionPtr>::arg_type;

//....

// deduction guide
template <typename Func, typename T = function_arg_t<Func>>
action_(Func) -> action_<Func, T>;
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.com](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wrc1q1fjs)

---

> I have this code which builds OK`
>
> `auto p1 = action_<myTestAction*, char>(testAction);`

This is because, you are telling the compiler **explicitly**, what are the template parameters type to deduce.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure the deduction guide can support several kinds of function types, I mean in my test code, the function type is `bool(std::string_view& sv)`, in this case, the T is actually `char`, but in other cases, the function type could be `bool(std::span<Token>)`, where the T is actually `Token` type. My initial guess is that the second template argument is depend on the first template argument. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you can have as many deduction guides as you need as long they do not conflict with each other.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/531Ybe37a

Comment: Hi, @MarekR thanks. I looked at your code, it has a `function_arg_t`, with this, I can get the function argument type from the function type, that's really nice. BTW, I have changed the code a little, because I need `// T == Token
using myTestActionSpan = bool(const std::span<Token>&);
constexpr bool funcSpan(const std::span<Token>&) { return true; }`, the `std::span` as the input stream view.

Comment: Hi, @JeJo sorry that I have a mistake, the previous comment is mainly response to your code for https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5cGG8E7c1 and it works quite well!

Comment: I would also thank @MarekR the deduction guide is telling the compiler if some special type of the function argument(in my case the function type) is used, the template argument can be also specified.

Comment: @JeJo can you directly put your code to the answer? My concern is that some day, the godbolt site get broken, and the code will be missing. Thanks.